# Выбор блока по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите решить проблему. Делаю карту офисов компании.

Вот макет на кодепен: https://codepen.io/denis-pawlowich/pen/qBOqBxp

Все сделал почти как надо, но как выполнить условие, чтобы по умолчанию отображался блок "Контакты 1"?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // CLICKABLE MAP
    $('#txmap a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $('#txmap a').attr("aria-pressed", "false");
        $(this).attr("aria-pressed", "true");
        $('.contact-card').hide().attr("aria-hidden", "true");
        $('#' + target).fadeIn(200).attr("aria-hidden", "false");
  });
});
```

---

Нашел решение с помощью добавление id к нужному блоку и функции имитирования клика:
 $("#clicks").click(); , но на карте по прежнему оно не выделяет регион офиса по умолчанию

Comment: какой регион офиса по умолчанию?

Answer (score 0):

У вас путаница в селекторе:

```
.st5:hover, svg a:focus .st5, svg a[aria-pressed="true"] .st1
```

Там где #clicks у вас st5, но aria-pressed="true" вы делаете на st1. Замените на a[aria-pressed="true"] .st5 будет работать